Consultas de dos tablas con mysql
tabla menu (id, producto, precio)

tabla ventas(folio, fecha, producto, cantidad, importe)

tengo la necesidad de hacer una consulta que muestre cuales son los productos que mas se venden en determinado tiempo, pero que incluya tambien los que no se venden, es decir deben estar todos los productos de la tabla menu
intente un left join pero no me muestra los que no se venden supongo por la condicion del join pero no se como hacerlo me podran ayudar por favor:
Intente esta consulta:
SELECT menu.producto, count(ventas.producto) as cant
FROM menu     
LEFT JOIN ventas     
ON menu.producto = ventas.producto where fecha between "2024-10-01" and "2024-12-07" 
group by menu.producto order by cant desc

Espero alguien pueda apoyarme. Gracias

Y eso no te manda un error?? Que datos muestra y cuales esperas conseguir? añade una tabla o una imagen como ejemplo.

Hola Excorpion, no me da error, pero solo me muestra los prodcutos que si se han vendido en ese periodo, yo necesito que me salgan todos los productos aunque no esten en la tabla de ventas (si estan en la tabla menu).

Puedes probar a mover la condición de la fecha DENTRO del ON en el JOIN. Ahora mismo la tienes del siguiente modo:
LEFT JOIN ventas     
ON menu.producto = ventas.producto
WHERE fecha BETWEEN "2024-10-01" AND "2024-12-07"

Al hacer el WHERE separado de la condición del JOIN, estás separando los datos que quieres incluir.
Prueba con:
LEFT JOIN ventas     
ON menu.producto = ventas.producto
AND fecha BETWEEN "2024-10-01" AND "2024-12-07"

Ahora, dentro de la condición del JOIN le estás diciendo que incluya los productos de ambas tablas con las mismas id Y además, los que sean entre esas fechas.
Acá el ejemplo completo a probar: (y he incluido alias)
SELECT 
    m.producto AS producto, 
    COUNT(v.producto) AS cant 
FROM menu m
LEFT JOIN ventas v
ON m.producto = v.producto 
AND v.fecha BETWEEN '2024-10-01' AND '2024-12-07'
GROUP BY m.producto 
ORDER BY cant DESC;


Hola nuevamente, ya proble la consulta justamente me da los resultados esperados, el unico problema es que tardo demasiado en mostrar los resultados

Cuantos registros son? no veo por que deberia demorarse, es una consulta simple

Son alrededor de 80 mil registros pero todas las demas consultas funciona bien, en realidad esto es algo que me esta causando algo de problemas para solucionar, estoy pensando en como obtener la informacion de alguna otra manera, es un sistema para un restaurante de un condominio, en el cual puedo ver ventas por departamento desde el 2011 cuando eche andar el programa y ahora estamos haciendo algunas mejoras y necesito esta informacion

Tiene problemas de indexación la BD? por que estás buscando entre 2 meses nada mas.

Hola por lo que veo te falta un campo en el diseño de las tablas, el cruce de tablas se hace por id (tipo numérico, único), por lo tanto se esta usando producto que se da por entendido que es de tipo varchar, agregar un nuevo campo llamado menu_id
tabla ventas(folio, fecha, producto, cantidad, importe, menu_id)

y la unión ocurre entra la tabla menu y ventas
ON menu.id = ventas.menu_id

y finalmente quedaría de la siguiente manera
SELECT menu.producto, count(ventas.producto) as cant
FROM menu     
LEFT JOIN ventas     
ON menu.id = ventas.menu_id
where fecha between "2024-10-01" and "2024-12-07" 
group by menu.producto order by cant desc


Hola Jonathan, muchas gracias intentare modificar la tabla agregando la columna que mencionas a ver como me va, la cosa que si son varios registros pero veo como le hago para hacer las pruebas
